# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setDefaults(I)V in class Lcom/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-translate

I'm trying to add the firebase translate feature by following the steps as per instructed in the page.
[text](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/translate-text)

but I'm getting this error
[image]

at getTranslator(options) method

```
// Create an English-German translator:
FirebaseTranslatorOptions options =
        new FirebaseTranslatorOptions.Builder()
                .setSourceLanguage(FirebaseTranslateLanguage.EN)
                .setTargetLanguage(FirebaseTranslateLanguage.DE)
                .build();
final FirebaseTranslator englishGermanTranslator =
        FirebaseNaturalLanguage.getInstance().getTranslator(options);
```

Kindly Help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact line of code that produces that error?

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because the runtime jars here is different from the compile time jars.

That is :

1. compile the source code with denpendency jars version 1 and produce app;
2. run the app with runtime dependency jars version 2;

version 1 and version 2 are different, so there occurs the error.